# Components are not loading in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, tomcat, amazon-ec2, react-router-dom

I am running my code on ec2-linux instance with the help of Tomcat .

When I try to load the components , using react-router-dom , components are not loading.

This is my index.html file

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my webpack.config.json file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    } ,

    module:{
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },{
       test:/\.s?css$/,
       use: [
         'style-loader',
         'css-loader',
         'sass-loader'
    ]
    }]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
};
```

This is my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter , Route  } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import './styles/styles.scss';

const ExpenseDashBoardPage = () => (
    <div>
        This is from my dashboard component.
    </div>
);

const AddExpensePage = () => (
    <div>
        This is my add expense component.
    </div>
);



const routes = (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path="/"  component={ExpenseDashBoardPage} exact={true}/>
            <Route path="/create"  component={AddExpensePage}/>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Expected Output For link

http://13.233.125.217/expensify-app/public/

is : This is from my dashboard components.

which I am getting properly.

But when I try to load create page by providing the link :

http://13.233.125.217/expensify-app/public/create

It is throwing 404 error.

Please , help me to solve the problem

Comment: change BrowserRouter to HashRouter and test the output

Comment: i think this is your server problem.. first try to load some sample html in your root. then transfer your react code

Comment: Hey @divine , it worked . Thanks a lot.